# Converter PDF To SWF FLASH - Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#

Boa noite, estou gerando pdf usando Itextsharp e preciso enviar para o cliente um swf, contudo estou com dificuldades, no client fica uma tela de flash em branca. Estou usando essa estratégia pois com o flash eu consigo bloquear as opções de imprimir o pdf e salvar como.
Algum programador ninja teria alguma dica de como fazer isso?

Comment: Você está com dificuldade de gerar o PDF ou de exibir ele dentro de um container SWF?

Comment: O pdf está gerado e a rotina para exibir o swf também. Minha dificuldade é em converter o pdf para swf.

Answer (score 0):

[Achei esta ferramenta aqui](http://www.swftools.org/download.html).

O código abaixo, [segundo esta pergunta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796115/how-can-i-convert-pdf-to-flash-for-the-web) [e este outro tópico aqui](http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1276342.htm), faz a conversão:

```
int pageNumber = 1;
string filename = @"MeuArquivo.pdf";
string outputfile = @"ArquivoConvertido.swf";
System.Diagnostics.Process pdf2swfprocess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pdf2swfprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF2SWF/pdf2swf.exe");
//pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = inputfile + "-o" + outputfile;
pdf2swfprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF2SWF/FONTS") + "\"" + " -p " + pageNumber + " " + filename + " -o " + filename + pageNumber + ".swf";

pdf2swfprocess.Start();
pdf2swfprocess.WaitForExit();
pdf2swfprocess.Close();
```

Comment: Esse código não funciona Cigano, não gera expetions e não gera o arquivo

Comment: Tentou rodar o executável na mão antes? Acredito que a resposta seja o aprimoramento deste código.

Comment: Opa, uncionou executando o comando pdf2swf.exe indicador.pdf -o teste.swf -f -T 9 -t -G -s . 
Só tem um detalhe que não é bom, quando abro o arquivo swf em um editor de flash ele fica pulando de forma automática as páginas.Seria bom conseguir adicionar um botão para trocar de forma manual.

Comment: Alguém tem ideia de como remover? na wiki (wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Pdf2swf) dos parâmetros do Pdf2swf não faz referencia  a como adicionar uma barra e
Nesse blog (http://workblog.neteos.eu/examples/view.php) e o swf dele aparece com barra.

Answer (score -1):

Encontrei a resposta precisa rodar dois comandos. O primeiro para gerar o swf 
 e o segundo comando para combinar o swf gerado com algum modelo padrão.
1) pdf2swf.exe indicador.pdf -o teste.swf 
2) swfcombine.exe C:\swftools\rfxview.swf viewport=plano1.swf -o plano1.swf

Comment: E como fica isso em código? Isso responde só metade da pergunta. No caso, sua aplicação tem que chamar o processo e recolher o resultado da saída.